# How to Load dynamic Image from httpHandlers in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, httphandler

I've got an ASP.NET application with a library that generates an Image. It is set up as follows:

In the Web.config I have a declaration in the **<httpHandlers>** section like so:

```
<add path="My.image.aspx" verb="GET" type="MyProject.Handlers.MyImageHandler, MyProject" validate="false"/>
```

This links up the code to generate the image to that path which is then used on my .aspx page like this:

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="My.image.aspx" BorderWidth="0" ID="myImage" runat="server"/>
```

When viewing this page normally, the image is loaded correctly.

However, I need to output this image to a PDF file, but because the PDF's won't interpret the page HTML with that URL correctly (says it cannot find resource, because these files are limited to interpreting only basic HTML/CSS), I wanted to try to load the Image in the code behind and output it to the PDF that way. However, I have no idea how to load this image in the code behind. I tried the following:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("My.image.aspx");
```

But had no luck. Is there a proper way to load this Image in the code behind from the httpHandler I have specified?

**EDIT:** I found a workaround, as I couldn't get the Image to load from the code behind. Instead, I have just used the <asp:Image> control to the load the file on the page and trigger the handler. When the handler creates the System.Drawing.Image file I was able to add it to the Session object for use later on that page. However, I still was unable to find a way to trigger all of that from the code behind without using a front end ASP control.

Answer (score 0):

you asp:image have and id as myImage

So in the code behind you can use it this way

```
using (Bitmap theImage = new Bitmap("My.image.aspx"))
{
   using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      theImage .Save(stream , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
      stream .WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
   }
}
```

Comment: 'System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("My.image.aspx")' will not load the image because it says it cannot find the file. The ASP.NET Image control doesn't contain a FromFile property, and finally the image on the ASPX is a different type of image from the System.Web.UI.WebControls library.

Comment: @user1048281 your right i got side tracked i have updated the answer

Comment: Well this works to load the Image. But I want to store the Image file as a System.Drawing.Image type for output. Edit: This is also the same thing I am doing already...just from the code behind.

Comment: @user1048281 see updated answer this will write the image to you outputstream

Comment: Gives the "Parameter is not valid." exception when loading the Bitmap the same exception as when trying this System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("My.image.aspx");

Comment: You can't load an image from a Handler like that, with the related URL specified in the Web.config. My question is how to do this another way because this way clearly does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I found a workaround, am adding it to the original post.